# AWS Terraform passing of multiple arn for Cloudfront function_association

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-cloudfront, terraform-provider-aws, aws-lambda-edge

I like to do a dynamic `function_assocation` to an AWS CloudFront resource. Instead of defining each function, I did something like the below.

```
resource "aws_cloudfront_function" "functions" {
  for_each = var.cf_lambda_functions

  name    = each.value.name
  comment = each.value.description
  runtime = each.value.runtime
  publish = each.value.publish
  code    = each.value.code
}
```

and for the `function_association`, I did something like the below.

```
dynamic "function_association" {
  for_each = aws_cloudfront_function.functions
  content {
    event_type = "viewer-request"
    function_arn = each.value.arn
  }
}
```

this gives me an error: `each.value cannot be used in this context`. How do you do this by passing multiple ARN of functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In dynamic blocks you can't use `each`. Instead it should be `function_association` in your case:

```
dynamic "function_association" {
  for_each = aws_cloudfront_function.functions
  content {
    event_type = "viewer-request"
    function_arn = function_association.value.arn
  }
}
```